# Angular 4 ng2-drag-drop: Performance issue

Tags: performance, angular, drag-and-drop

I'm using **ng2-drag-drop** plugin for drag and drop. I've 1000 divisions on which I can drop an element. In this case, the onDrop method is calling after 10 seconds. I just tested with 2 divisions, and it was pretty fast. How can I solve this performance issue?

Here is my template:

```
<table border="1" class='bdx-table-plate'>
<tr>
    <th *ngFor="let column of columns" class="plate-row-col-header">{{column}}</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let sample of plate  | groupBy: 'row_id' | values ">
    <td class="plate-row-col-header">{{sample[0].row_id}}</td>
    <td class="well-parent" draggable='true' droppable='true'
        *ngFor="let well of sample "
        (onDrop)="onDropWell($event, well)" [attr.well]='well'><span
        (click)="selectWell($event, plate, well)" class="well event"
        id="{{well.id}}" draggable  (onDragStart)="initDrag()"
        [dragData]='well'
        [ngClass]="{ 'emptyCell' : !well.name, 'well-select' : well.is_selected,  'well-unselect' : !well.is_selected, 'bdx-rerun' : well.is_rerun}"
        [ngStyle]="{'background-color': well.bg_color}"
        [attr.well]='well'>{{well.name}}</span> <!-- {{well.plate_id}} {{well.row_id}} {{well.col_id}} -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my typescript:

```
 onDropWell(e, droppedObjData) {
    alert('Dropped!!');
}
```

My problem is,
onDropWell is getting called after 10 seconds due to many elements. I've around 1000 cells in entire table

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don't share your code.

Comment: Updated my question with my code

Comment: Might be because of using the `groupBy` pipe on your code? Angular team strongly discourages the use of pipes for filtering and ordering because of performance issues. Read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)